# Setting the CRS in QGIS for my shapefiles which have changed direction

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, google-earth-engine

I am relatively new to QGIS. I have tried CRS's across Central Asia but they keep distorting my shapefiles like shown. I made the shapefiles in Google Earth Engine and have exported them over.

https://wetransfer.com/downloads/40508d651fd6032fc510557630575a3720230423152708/fec8a72885eff96746d0ff3b921e177920230423152708/2df1f1

Here's how they look in GEE:

[image]

The shapefiles have changed direction in QGIS:

[image: QGIS snapshot]

Comment: It looks like you may have your longitude (x) and latitude (y) values the wrong way around.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! It looks like you have a coordinate system problem, see if any of the suggestions at https://ihatecoordinatesystems.com/ help.

Comment: Thank you for your help. How do I change the X and Y around of a shapefile in qgis?

Comment: Please post your shapefile. (WeTransfer, DropBox, etc)

Comment: I shared my shapefiles via Wetransfer. If you could help at all I would hugely appreciate it

Comment: Those are just the SHP files. Also need PRJ, DBF, and SHX files.

Comment: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/40508d651fd6032fc510557630575a3720230423152708/fec8a72885eff96746d0ff3b921e177920230423152708/2df1f1.     Sorry, here are all the files

Comment: I drag and drop the files you provided to QGIS and they appear in the correct place, as in your first screenshot. So no problem at all with the files. Don't know what's going on in your case, you should provide more information.

Comment: What is the best CRS to use? When I set the CRS is when they changed direction. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You don't need to or want to set the CRS. QGIS automatically picks up the PRJ file which is WGS84. Drag-n-dropping into QGIS puts it in the right place.

Comment: Thank you. The problem was the file extension weren't in my browser. How do I add shapefiles and extension into my browser?

Comment: More details please on what you're doing. Is this a QGIS question or a GEE question?